# Account Auto-Numbering

Tags: account, auto-number

I'd like to know how to Auto-Number all Accounts upon creation by User Interface or Data Loader with a unique number. Also, I'd like to include existing Accounts in the initial count, then incrementally numbered after.

What is the cleanest, fastest, most consistent way to accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can create Auto number field on your account object

[image]

and on next screen select **Generate Auto Number for existing records** checkbox as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your `Custom_Account_Number` field as a `Text` data type, load your assigned numbers for the existing account records (make sure there is no duplicates), and then convert this field data type to `Auto Number`, defining a starting number.